# Get match after specific regex in js

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to get the match after the regex in js?

Assume I have str as;

```
fun.call("className.serviseName"[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])

blablablabalbalbabalabalbal

fun.call("className2.serviseName2"[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

I want to get only`"className.serviseName"` and "className2.serviseName2"`

What have I done so far?

```js
var str = 'fun.call("className.serviseName"[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])';
var arr = str.match(/fun.call\(\".*\"/g); // returns ["fun.call("className.serviseName""]
```

But I want to get only and exactly : `className.serviseName` and `className2.serviseName2`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'fun.call("className.serviseName"[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])';
str = str.split('"');
console.log(str[1]);
```

Comment: Why did you include jQuery?

Comment: Forgot to remove it... :) Thanks @Cerbrus For Editing. Next time I will take care for changes you had made

Answer (score -1):

Put the matching part in bracers `()` and then select it with the index of the returning array. And don't make it global (`g`).

```js
var str = 'fun.call("className.serviseName"[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])';
var arr = str.match(/fun.call\(\"(.*)\"/)[1];

console.log(arr);
```

If you await multiple results in one `string` you have to do a loop with the `regex`. The globally `g` is needed.

```js
var str = 'fun.call("className.serviseName"[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])fun.call("className.serviseName2"[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])';
var regEx = /fun.call\(\"(.+?)\"/g;
var match;

while( match = regEx.exec(str) ) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: The `g` flag doesn't mean _"greedy"_. It's _"global"_.

Comment: But I can have thousands of this regex in the text that I want to parse, so I want to get all of them. That's why I think about using g

Comment: The `g` flag's function is unrelated to the "greedy" concept in regexes.

Comment: No, `a+` is greedy (because it would find as many characters as possible), vs `a+?` which is lazy (as few characters as possible). `/g/` means "global" because it would not stop after the first match and will check the entire string.

Comment: Okay okay, just changed. Thanks folks. ;)

Comment: Should first validate that there is a `match()` array result, because it can give an error if there is not match

Comment: extended my answer, @user6468132